# FizzBuzz textContent issue

Tags: javascript, html, fizzbuzz

I'm using the old FizzBuzz exercise, and utilizing textContent, trying to load a page with each of the values listed one after the other, vertically. Right now I'm getting this instead:

> 12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz11Fizz1314FizzBuzz1617Fizz19BuzzFizz2223FizzBuzz26Fizz2829FizzBuzz3132Fizz34BuzzFizz3738FizzBuzz41Fizz4344FizzBuzz4647Fizz49BuzzFizz5253FizzBuzz56Fizz5859FizzBuzz6162Fizz64BuzzFizz6768FizzBuzz71Fizz7374FizzBuzz7677Fizz79BuzzFizz8283FizzBuzz86Fizz8889FizzBuzz9192Fizz94BuzzFizz9798FizzBuzz

Here is my code:

```js
var n = 1, str = ""

while (n <= 100) {
  if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
    str = str + "FizzBuzz"
  } else if (n % 3 === 0) {
    str = str + "Fizz"
  } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
    str = str + "Buzz"
  }
  else {
    str = str + n
  }
  n++
}

document.querySelector(".container").textContent = str
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="container"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could it be as simple as appending a line break to each "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz", or number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `textContent`, since it doesn't include any formatting. Use `innerHTML` and put `<br>` tags after each item.

```js
var n = 1, str = ""

while (n <= 100) {
  if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
    str = str + "FizzBuzz<br>";
  } else if (n % 3 === 0) {
    str = str + "Fizz<br>";
  } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
    str = str + "Buzz<br>";
  }
  else {
    str = str + n + '<br>';
  }
  n++;
}

document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML = str
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="container"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh. Much appreciated!